# Regex expression to fetch correct value in python

Tags: python, regex

I have below repeated pattern of data in a text file(info.txt). I need to read only 5 components from each block

- SENDER
- RECEIVER
- OBJ_CLASS
- JOBN_PAR
- CONVTAB

> ```
> SENDER=DEMO RECEIVER=REC OBJ_CLASS=message
>   JOBN_PAR=JOB.NAME "ROLLBACK=NO" "CONVTAB=message_to_convert_document.cfg" "REST=NO"
>   EVN_TYPE=USER
>   JOB_SEQU=N
>   JOB_PRIO=0
>   TIME_WINDOW=
>   HC_DIRECTION=1
>   POP_ENABLE=Y
> ```

I have written below python code to read the above pattern of data, It reads all the values until 2nd Line and attaches the values to JOBN_PAR and CONVTAB, while I want only value corresponding to the CONVTAB="" and JOBN_PAR="" in my output

```
import re
with open("info.txt", "r") as f:
    s = f.read().replace('"','')

field_labels = [
                'SENDER', 
                'RECEIVER',
                'OBJ_CLASS',
                'JOBN_PAR',
                'CONVTAB'
                ]

pat = '=(.*)\s*'.join(field_labels) + '=(.*)\s'
pat = re.compile(pat)

print(pat)
data = pat.findall(s)
print(data)
```

**Outcome**

> [('DEMO ', 'REC ', 'message', 'JOB.NAME ROLLBACK=NO ',
>   'message_to_convert_document.cfg  REST=NO')]

**Expected Output**
[('DEMO ', 'REC ', 'message', 'JOB.NAME', 'message_to_convert_document.cfg')]

Comment: What separates the blocks of data? Are there any differences between the blocks?

Comment: `.*` is greedy - look it up https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html - which in this case doesn't matter until the last `.*` in the regex.

Comment: @Patrolin: empty space is between each blocks

Comment: @barny: thanks for the link, I will work out on the above link to better my understanding in re

Comment: @codenamebazinga: What _exactly_ do you mean by empty space? Spaces? A new line? Two new lines?

Comment: here with empty space, I meant a single empty line. Sorry for any confusion

Answer (score 0):

Using lambda expression generate regex string and then compile it as below.
Its giving correct output

```
pattern = '.*?'.join(list(map(lambda x: '(?:' + x + r'=(.*?)\s+)', field_labels)))
patternReg = re.compile(pattern, re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Can you explain what your modifications to the regex do, i.e. why did they solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`=(.*)\s` will also match blocks that contain whitespace, as long as there is whitespace at the end. Since regex matching is greedy you can't prevent this without explicitly excluding it in the pattern. If you know that the value will never contain whitespace you can use `=([^\s]*)\s` instead, which will match on text that contains anything but whitespace. This introduces another problem, however, since now the fields are not longer strictly seperated by whitespace, so the regex will not match at all. To solve this, you can replace the `\s*` that seperates the seperate fields by a `\s.*`, which still requires whitespace but allows for any characters after that. Thus, the final regex to join on is `=([^\s]*)\s.*`. This gives the required result:

```py
>>> text = """
...     SENDER=DEMO RECEIVER=REC OBJ_CLASS=message
...       JOBN_PAR=JOB.NAME "ROLLBACK=NO" "CONVTAB=message_to_convert_document.cfg" "REST=NO"
...       EVN_TYPE=USER
...       JOB_SEQU=N
...       JOB_PRIO=0
...       TIME_WINDOW=
...       HC_DIRECTION=1
...       POP_ENABLE=Y
... """.replace('"', '') # replicating the replacement done by the original code
>>> import re
>>> field_labels = [
...                 'SENDER', 
...                 'RECEIVER',
...                 'OBJ_CLASS',
...                 'JOBN_PAR',
...                 'CONVTAB'
...                 ]
>>> pat = '=([^\s]*)\s.*'.join(field_labels) + '=([^\s]*)\s'
>>> repat = re.compile(pat)
>>> print(repat.findall(text))
[('DEMO', 'REC', 'message', 'JOB.NAME', 'message_to_convert_document.cfg')]
```

Comment: You neglected to mention your little tweak to the input string `replace('"', '')` - couldn't you get the regex to ignore the " around some label=value strings?

Comment: @barny I added that conversion because the original post applies it in the reading of the file. Perhaps I could have mentioned it explicitly, but I wanted to ensure the results would be consistent with the data the poster was reading.

Comment: I edited the answer with a comment to clarify the `replace`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, your pattern is this:

```
'SENDER=(.*)\\s*RECEIVER=(.*)\\s*OBJ_CLASS=(.*)\\s*JOBN_PAR=(.*)\\s*CONVTAB=(.*)\\s'
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/UBDqgO/1/) you can see that you full match is the whole string up to `message_to_convert_document.cfg`. For `(.*)`, as `ROLLBACK` is not in the field list and space is also goes into `.` it attached with the value of `JOBN_PAR`

I did some improvement in your code to get the proper output. I went through one by one field.

```
import re
with open("in.txt", "r") as f:
    s = f.read().replace('"','')

field_labels = [
                'SENDER', 
                'RECEIVER',
                'OBJ_CLASS',
                'JOBN_PAR',
                'CONVTAB'
                ]
pat = '=(.*)\s*'.join(field_labels) + '=(.*)\s'
pat = re.compile(pat)
print(pat)
data = []

for field in field_labels: // it will also get the value if a field is present multiple time
    pat = field + '=([^=\s\n]*)' // added \n here otherwise if you want the value of last one you should not get
    pat = re.compile(pat)
    data += pat.findall(s)


print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking for `[field_label]=[field_value]` pairs, instead of trying to match a huge chunk of text.

First, have a non-capturing group, that defines allowed field labels:

```
labels_group = "(?:" + "|".join(field_labels) + ")"
```

Then, define what a `[field_label]=[field_value]` pair looks like:

```
pat = f'{labels_group}=(.+?)\s+'
# if you dont like f-strings: pat = '{}==(.+?)\s+'.format(labels_group)
```

An important thing to note is that for the field value, we want to match as few characters as possible (using `+?`) before the whitespace.